# Resetting the "Recent places" in "save as" dialog to default

Tags: macos, finder

I am using OS X 10.11.6.  I wanted to increase the items listed in the "recent places" in the "save as dialog", so I followed the instruction here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5185944?tstart=0

and typed the command in the terminal:

```
defaults write .GlobalPreferences NSNavRecentPlacesLimit -int 12
```

Then I discovered that it didn't work, and instead my "recent places" is not changing anymore.

So I tried to reset by typing the below in the terminal:

```
defaults delete .GlobalPreferences NSNavRecentPlaces
```

Now the recent places is completely gone in the save as dialog.  I created a new user with admin right, logged into it and also found the recent places is gone from the save as dialog.

I also tried to download OnyX for El Capitan → Parameters → General → Restore Defaults, but this didn't work either.

How can I reset the recent places back to the original?

Comment: Next time you want to mod, don't use global preferences ;-) and make a backup!

Answer (score 1):

With El Capitan 10.11.6, here's the output from `defaults read .GlobalPreferences NSNavRecentPlaces` on my system.

```
(
    "~/Desktop/news",
    "~/Documents/text",
    "~/Documents/text/news",
    "~/Documents/astronomy",
    "/Volumes/Video"
)
```

Try `defaults write .GlobalPreferences NSNavRecentPlaces -array /Applications` to restore a value for the `NSNavRecentPlaces` key.

There is no `NSNavRecentPlacesLimit` key in `.GlobalPreferences` for El Capitan on my system. The following list of keys are part of the output from `defaults find NSNav` which is a long list. I assume these are the default settings. Here are the `NSNav` keys:

```
Found 9 keys in domain 'Apple Global Domain': {
    NSNavPanelFileLastListModeForOpenModeKey = 2;
    NSNavPanelFileLastListModeForSaveModeKey = 2;
    NSNavPanelFileListModeForOpenMode2 = 2;
    NSNavPanelFileListModeForSaveMode2 = 2;
    NSNavPanelSidebarKeyForOpen =     (
    );
    NSNavPanelSidebarKeyForSave =     (
    );
    NSNavRecentPlaces =     (
        "~/Desktop/news",
        "~/Documents/text",
        "~/Documents/text/news",
        "~/Documents/astronmy",
        "/Volumes/Video"
    );
    NSNavSortOrder =     (
        NSNavDisplayNameFileProperty,
        1
    );
    "NSNavSortOrder_10.6" =     (
        displayName,
        1
    );
}
```

Try `defaults delete .GlobalPreferences NSNavRecentPlacesLimit` to remove the key you added. The [discussions article](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5185944) seems to be about OS X versions before El Capitan and may not be relevant or useful with OS 10.11.